# IOS - Superview is catching touch events on landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, landscape, superview

I've a UIViewController created programmatically, and when I insert its view to my general view, the 300 pixels in the bottom of the UIView aren't getting any touch event, the touch event is being caught by the superview, the main UIView.

The important fact is that only occurs when I'm on landscape mode.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here goes an screenshot, the oranged background is the UIView that have its own UIViewController and that needs be touched, but the as I said, the last pixels from bottom (aprox. 275) are being catched by the main UIViewController. So the buttons are never called.
Only on landscape mode!

[image: Gallery screenshot]

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: Set the clipsToBounds to YES for the view you're adding and see if you see the entire view. If not probably you have a problem with autoresizing masks.

Comment: Yes!! Is not showing the entire UIView! Let's investigate about masks..

Comment: I'm not really sure about, but with this line of code, the problem has gone:   `galleryViewController.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingNone);`